# Create bootable macOS USB for a non Apple computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb, macosx

I tried several ways to create a bootable macOS USB for a non Apple personal computer. I expected it to work exactly like my bootable Ubuntu USB. macOS bootable USB seems to be working differently. It seems that it only works on Mac. My laptop does not detect my Mac bootable USB as a bootable one on startup.

Is it possible to create a bootable macOS USB for by Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 dual boot HP laptop with persistence (optional) so that I can use it by just plugging it in during boot up for building my flutter projects?

Is it possible to create a bootable macOS USB, by using Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 dual boot HP laptop, with persistence (optional) so that I can use it by just plugging it in during boot up for building my flutter projects?

Comment: There are multiple type of ISO files, thus many ISO writing tools cannot successfully write all types (particularly if written to cope only with specific ISOs). Your question doesn't appear to be about Ubuntu though (there is no Ubuntu 20 either, desktop & server releases use *yy.mm* format, *snap* based Core releases use *yy* but I suspect it's not what you mean). https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Still I need to know if creating such a USB is possible or not.

Comment: Most of us likely don't use mac's, thus have no reason to know what type(s) of ISO files macOS uses, nor if it varies on release/version, let alone which version you're asking about. For best chance of decent results, you should provide that detail for us, as we are likely to know what programs will write specific types of ISO files.  I'd believe it's possible yes, but details would need to known before I'd know what program writes that type ISO file (will a `dd` work along, or what options are required to make it work etc)

Comment: What you're asking about is not a macOS installation USB. it's called a Hackintosh.

Comment: You can't run macOS on anything other than a Mac without massive effort.

Comment: You can easily (not compared to linux though) install and use MacOS in VirtualBox or VMWare via a hackintosh VMDK . See [this](https://www.geekrar.com/install-macos-catalina-on-virtualbox-on-windows-pc-new/) . I've tried this and it works for me but it's very slow both in booting and in regular jobs .

Comment: And if you're concerned about the legal issues , as long as you're not using it in a public computer like the ones in the libraries , you are able to use it  without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to [David Anderson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/107222/david-anderson) and [Nimesh Nima](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema) for the answer.

Microsoft offers Windows to Go which can be run from a flash drive on different machines. Many Linux distributions offer a live version which also can be run from a flash drive on different machines. Some also offer persistence which allow data to be saved between boots. Apple's MacOS can be installed on USB HDD and USB SSD which can be run on different Macs. AFAIK, MacOS is not designed to run from a flash drive.

MacOS doesn't generally support installing and running on non supported hardware, i.e. non Apple computers. Apple, unlike Microsoft doesn't license its operating system for running on commodity PCs.

> It seems that it only works on Mac. My laptop does not detect my Mac bootable USB as a bootable one on startup.

This is by design. A MacOS bootable USB can only boot a compatible Apple Mac computer.

> Is it possible to create a bootable MacOS USB for by Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 dual boot HP laptop with persistence (optional) so that I can use it by just plugging it in during boot up for building my flutter projects?

Generally speaking, no.